# Categorical Explorations: Seeking Guidance for Trace, Algebras, and More

Tags: category-theory, superalgebra, supergeometry

I have a question for experts in the field of category. While I haven't taken a formal course in category theory at my university, I've undertaken a thesis project that delves into the concepts presented in Varadarajan's book on supersymmetry for mathematicians. My focus lies on super linear algebra and supermanifolds.

During my research, I encountered a section within the realm of super linear algebra, titled "The Categorical Point of View." In this section, I encountered the definition of a trace within the category. I then proceeded to prove its reduction to the ordinary trace in $\textbf{Vect} $, which represents the category of finite vector spaces. It also reduced to the supertrace in $\textbf{sVect} $, a category dealing with $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded free modules of finite rank over a supercommutative algebra. Additionally, I provided a definition of a Lie algebra within the category, along with an example pertaining to $\textbf{Vect}$, and so on.

Based on this foundation, I've developed a solid understanding of categories and their role as a generalization of various mathematical structures. I am eager to embark on a research journey that explores categories encompassing definitions of trace, algebras, and related concepts from their fundamental principles.

With this in mind, I'm seeking recommendations from category theory experts for a book that aligns with my preferred style of exposition, similar to Varadarajan's approach. I've already read Emily Riehl's book, but I'm interested in exploring another text that aligns with Varadarajan's style of writing.